Does MySQL support '+/- infinity' numeric value?
Does MySQL support 'infinity' numeric value?
I know Pl/pgSQL support the 'Infinity' value

Is MySQL support the 'infinity' value ?
If you have any suggestions or any alternative of 'Infinity' declaration, please share once....
I'm still searching 'infinity' validation in MySQL ...

Look at this.

Thanks for suggestion ... @CardinalSystem
Yes, it's a grate explanation
